# iAd not showing banner ads

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tableview, iad

I am building an app in which I want to us iAd banners. the viewcontroller in which I want to show the ad is a UIViewController. I am using storyboards. I implemented the iAd banner exactly as apple shows/demonstrates here:

- add iAd framework
- import `"<iAd/iAd.h>"` header
- inserted     `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;`

but when I run my app, no iAd is showing up. do I forget something? Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had to sign the iAd contract in itunes connect, which I had not done yet. it works fine now!

Comment: Hi, I'm currently facing the same problem as you. Other than signing with the iAd contract, do I have to write any code in the view controller? Because I'm using [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_iAds_into_an_iOS_7_App) tutorial and in it, only putting the line `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;` in the `viewDidLoad` enables it but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: follow the steps that I describe in my question and let me know if it works ;)

Comment: I have it exactly like you have described. A storyboard app. I added and imported the iAd framework. Added this line ` self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;` to `viewDidLoad` but no ad shows up in the view controller. Where should I sign the iAd contract?

Comment: using itunes connect. I don't remember everything because that's a while ago, but you may also have to add some bank accounts to make it work. Furthermore, are you testing on your iphone of on simulator? Go to settings on your iphone, Developer and set the fill rate to 100%. that may do the trick as well.

Comment: I'm using the simulator. I'll give it a try. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a bit different issue, but the answer fits to your question as well. I updated my old xib file (was from XCode 5.1) to use `Size Classes` in XCode 6.0. After the update ads showed only in iPhone 4 - 5 and 5s. iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus was without banners (simulators showed the same results as the external devices). When using xib file and using

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
```

in my situation I moved this command from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear` and banner showed up. Now I can see banners in all devices.

Answer (score 0):

In your .h :

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
```

Add a banner view in your xib file and link this banner view with an IBOutlet

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet ADBannerView *iAdBannerView;
```

add the following code to display your ad :

```
#pragma mark - ADBannerViewDelegate
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    NSLog(@"banner loaded");

    // Display BannerView
    _iAdBannerView.hidden = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                     animations:^{
                         _iAdBannerView.alpha = 1.0f;
                     }];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Print error
    NSLog(@"error banner failed :\n%@", error);

    // Hide BannerView
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                     animations:^{
                         _iAdBannerView.alpha = 0.0f;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         _iAdBannerView.hidden = YES;
                     }];
}
```

and normally your adbanner will appear when you receive and ad and disappear otherwise.