# ADBanner in iOS 7 self.canDisplayBannerAds

Tags: ios, ios7, iad, adbannerview

I'm trying to integrate iAd in iOS 7 app. According to Apple tutorial, one just have to use method:
    self.canDisplayBannerAds
and iAd will work without a hitch. As I use it according to the tutorials, it gives a blank white screen. How to integrate iAds then? Do I have to use ADBannerViewDelegate so something else. Kindly explain

Comment: Have you signed the iAd contract? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934549/iad-not-showing-banner-ads).

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about the simulator but if your testing on a device you need to do the following. Go into your settings select developer and select fill rate then 100%.

Answer (score 1):

do you figure out mentioned issue?
I guess you need to implement the adbannerviewdelegate to handle load, unload, failed load scenarios. The blank white screen may be caused by network connectivity.

Comment: Yes adBannerDelegate method has to be implemented... in it are methods for adDidLoad or didFailToLoad in which we have to position Ad and remove it from view respectively. BTW u can check this out   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934549/iad-not-showing-banner-ads .... I haven't tried it but it says u have to sign iAd contract. If u try it and it works plz inform me too, cheers :)

Comment: You can't use the iAd delegate methods if you enable them using self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES. If you want to use the delegate methods you have to use the old way of adding ads.